# How to read values in excel file without using pandas, openpyxl etc...in python??

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

How to read values from excel file **without** using any *inbuilt* function?
Please share your answers

Comment: openpyxl, for example, is over *50000 lines of code* - do you really think you'd be able to do it with significantly less?

Answer (score -2):

you can try converting the xls file to csv first (you can use [this tool](https://cloudconvert.com/xls-to-csv))
now once you have the csv file you can simply:

```
with open('filename.csv','r') as file:
    data=file.readlines()
```

now we can print this data either with a simple `print(data)` or `print(''.join(data)` for better readibility in the terminal

Comment: using external tools to process files imposes serious data-security issues. Do not recommend this approach.